# Tensorflow. Could not open Checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I have built and trained a tensorflow model, but unfortunately, the checkpoint file cannot be open as shown below by an error.

```
Now there isn't an error, but a bunch of warnings that don't really tell you anything.
```

This happens when I run the evalutation code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP"

ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)

def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs()
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess)
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)

    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run(top_k_op))

def main(argv = None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

The next is how I had generated the checkpoint file:

```
                if step % 2 == 0:
                    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'model.ckpt')
                    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = step)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that created the checkpoint? It would be helpful to see both parts.

Comment: Sure , but I am afraid its a different error now after several modifications. I will repost the code and error.